# Emacs shell mode open file in buffer

Tags: shell, emacs, ssh, terminal

My setup:

- Emacs terminal mode (`emacs -nw`)
- inside it, use the shell mode (invoked with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ansi-term`)
- inside this shell, connect to a remote server with ssh

Suppose I'm browsing the remote server inside the shell and find a file I want to edit. Is there a command to open it as a parallel buffer/window?

The only method I know to open a file from the shell is to do `emacs -nw` again, which isn't quite convenient because a) I don't keep the shell open and b) it's really a different Emacs session, so for instance the "yank buffer" is different.

Edit: if there is a different/better way to work with a remote server with Emacs I'm just as interested; it's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's best to use tramp.

I have this shortcut (I call it with `smex`):

```
(defun connect-remote ()
  (interactive)
  (dired "/user@domain.com:/"))
```

This opens a dired buffer on the remote. You just use it as any dired buffer.

I've had a function to open a term from dired for a while, but I've
added an option to ssh from a tramp dired buffer just now:

```
(defun dired-open-term ()
  "Open an `ansi-term' that corresponds to current directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-dir (dired-current-directory)))
    (term-send-string
     (terminal)
     (if (file-remote-p current-dir)
         (let ((v (tramp-dissect-file-name current-dir t)))
           (format "ssh %s@%s\n"
                   (aref v 1) (aref v 2)))
       (format "cd '%s'\n" current-dir)))))

(defun terminal ()
  "Switch to terminal. Launch if nonexistent."
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*terminal*")
      (switch-to-buffer "*terminal*")
    (term "/bin/bash")))
```

And this is the shortcut that I use:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "`") 'dired-open-term)
```

Comment: I can't manage to invoke dired with the user@domain thing as parameter. It says it doesn't exist...

Comment: Did you substitute "user2460978@domain-or-ip-address:/"?

Comment: yes: if I usually connect to the server with
$> ssh MyUser@MyServer
and then type the password,
I tried with
dired "/MyUser@MyServer:/"
And the reply is:
Directory /home/xxx/"MyUser@MyServer:/" inaccessible or nonexistent

Comment: I already managed to fix it. Thanks. And I gotta add that Dired is heaven for this job. Feeling the Emacs power right now

Comment: I am getting following error: `Setting current directory: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [tramp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) from within your original emacs session to browse the remote server via ssh, using dired.  Then, any remote file you open is opened in your local emacs session.

If you prefer to avoid dired and want to browse with a shell, you can prepend the remote location (/name@host:/path/from/pwd) to the file name.  You can automate that with a function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on those options? I'm very newbie with Emacs. Thanks!